# .between() - Inclusive or Exclusive?

Tags: java, android, objectbox

Did not see this specified in the documentation -

Is the .between() query **Inclusive** or **Exclusive**?

eg:
I perform a query on an INT field that is BETWEEN 3 and 4.
Will it return ANY results? (Fields that are set to `3` or `4`? Or none, because it's an int field and nothing between those can be stored?)

Comment: TL;DR: inclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed doesn't appear to be documented, at least not for java. The C++ docs have an explanation:

> finds objects with property value between a and b (including a and b)

https://objectbox.io/docfiles/c/current/classobx_1_1Property.html#a1bd5e01f8047b81e05d00cb49333d360

If you trust the authors to be consistent between languages, then the answer is **inclusive**.

Comment: Yeah, SQL (in general) is the same, inclusive. Right NOW, I'm working as if it is. Since I'm using decimals in my actual code (with small, high accuracy), am hoping I don't have to do any magic number padding! Thanks!

Comment: It's inclusive. Thanks, Javadoc will be updated with next update!